# PHP curl to self to avoid FastCGI timeout

Tags: php, loops, curl, timeout, fastcgi

So here is my dilemma.  I need to pull several hundred API calls worth of data, parse them one at a time, and log matching data.  My problem is this takes awhile and I'm on shared hosting and my FastCGI busy timeout cant be altered (Web Host won't do it because of shared hosting I believe).  So I'm completely stumped on how to get around this.  I can't do CLI because it's a user facing tool where they input a list of data and thats what I match against.  So once the input is recieved I need the PHP to run by itself until completed (probably awhile like couple hours).

I tried everything and nothing works.  At this point to try and trick the system I have the file being self-referential instead of a loop but that doesnt seem to work.  I think thats my only way (unless someone has a better idea) and I'm trying to figure out how to make every call back on itself "restart" in the eyes of FastCGI.  HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) then you can always create either another PHP script to actually do the execution or some other program or script to do it, and then call that script with `exec` so you can have it run on the machine instead of through FastCGI. You'd then want to use some sort of progress tracking in your script to keep track of how far it's gotten, or when it's done, and then have a page to check on the progress of a request :)

Note: This really isn't a great idea for a production solution, but it will work better than figuring out a recursive curl call :)

Comment: Any better ideas for production?  Thanks for the input too :)

Comment: Dont use shared hosting ;) this will definitely be a good enough solution, though, just make clean your input to avoid executing malicious code

Comment: Yeah it's for a client lol.  As a side note I just realized what I did is working.  It just breaks the browser connection so I thought it was broken.  Is what I'm doing bad in any way?  Like how its setup to post back onto itself?

Comment: Youll have the same problem since each subsequent curl call will need to wait for the next one to finish (recursively) so your method shouldnt change anything

Comment: Well the script ends right after that and doesnt bother waiting for a response so won't the parent script just exit?

Comment: If you set your timeout to be somewhat low, then yes you should be fine. Keep in mind, though, you need a way of eventually giving the user the requested information, correct?

Comment: Not in this case.  I had ignore_user_abort set to true and it sends output to the ajax call as soon as the information is received.  The script ends naturally though right after it calls itself so I think I'm good.